# I serialized a WebSocket in NodeJS now it's just a object how would I deserialize it but to a WebSocket with all it's functions?

Tags: node.js, json, websocket

basically what I did is convert a WebSocket class from the `ws` library into JSON data
and a piped it through one of my clusters.

like this:

```js
cluster.fork().send({
    webSocket: this.webSocket,
});
```

and on the cluster's end:

```js
process.on("message", (message) => {
    let webSocket = message.webSocket;
});
```

But since piping it through `fork.send` it will serialize my data into JSON.

Since JSON doesn't serialize functions I need a way to get my WebSocket back will it's information.

Comment: This would take a bit more work since you likely need to at list call something like star or int. (Doubt it would work after that) For socket to function you need to make a connection so list you can expect is some params from witch you would be able to initiate socket on another end

Comment: Try maybe with a third party library?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript
You should be able to serialize functions and more.